# How to install pillow on Namecheap server

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, namecheap

I'm Trying to host a django-webapplication on namecheap hosting.
when i tried to install pillow its showing following error ->

```
Collecting pillow   Using cached Pillow-9.0.1.tar.gz (49.5 MB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done   WARNING: Generating metadata for package pillow produced metadata for project name unknown. Fix your #egg=pillow fragments. Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/a3/f61a9a7ff7969cdef2a6e0383a346eb327495d20d25a2de5a088dbb543a6/Pillow-9.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=6c8bc8238a7dfdaf7a75f5ec5a663f4173f8c367e5a39f87e720495e1eed75fa (from https://pypi.org/simple/pillow/) (requires-python:>=3.7): Requested unknown from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/a3/f61a9a7ff7969cdef2a6e0383a346eb327495d20d25a2de5a088dbb543a6/Pillow-9.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=6c8bc8238a7dfdaf7a75f5ec5a663f4173f8c367e5a39f87e720495e1eed75fa has inconsistent name: filename has 'pillow', but metadata has 'unknown'   Using cached Pillow-9.0.0.tar.gz (49.5 MB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done   WARNING: Generating metadata for package pillow produced metadata for project name unknown. Fix your
#egg=pillow fragments. Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/43/3e286c93b9fa20e233d53532cc419b5aad8a468d91065dbef4c846058834/Pillow-9.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=ee6e2963e92762923956fe5d3479b1fdc3b76c83f290aad131a2f98c3df0593e (from https://pypi.org/simple/pillow/) (requires-python:>=3.7): Requested unknown from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/43/3e286c93b9fa20e233d53532cc419b5aad8a468d91065dbef4c846058834/Pillow-9.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=ee6e2963e92762923956fe5d3479b1fdc3b76c83f290aad131a2f98c3df0593e has inconsistent name: filename has 'pillow', but metadata has 'unknown'   Using cached Pillow-8.4.0.tar.gz (49.4 MB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done Building wheels for collected packages: pillow   Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [144 lines of output]
      /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      building 'PIL._imaging' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
      building 'PIL._imagingtk' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
      building 'PIL._imagingmath' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/Tk
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingtk.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingtk.o
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingmath.o
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/libImaging
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      building 'PIL._imagingft' extension
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingft.o
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      building 'PIL._imagingmorph' extension
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingmorph.o
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION="8.4.0" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imaging.o
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow   Running setup.py clean for pillow Failed to build pillow Installing collected packages: pillow   Running setup.py install for pillow ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pillow did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [143 lines of output]
      /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      building 'PIL._imaging' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/libImaging
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION="8.4.0" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imaging.o
      building 'PIL._imagingtk' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/Tk
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingtk.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingtk.o
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      building 'PIL._imagingft' extension
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingft.o
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      building 'PIL._imagingmorph' extension
      building 'PIL._imagingmath' extension
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingmorph.o
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-xyrdaphv/pillow_4038575f85f44929a26335ac03479963 -I/home/todaizeq/virtualenv/kestatevision/3.8/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_imagingmath.o
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> pillow

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip. hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: `unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory` looks like `gcc`is not isntalled or environment variables are not set correctly.

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: I know this is late, but you should install an earlier version of pillow or change your hosting plan. even changing the python version wont work. If you figured it out, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Install specific Pillow version: If you encounter issues with the latest version of Pillow, you can try installing a specific version preferably an old version. For example, to install Pillow version 8.3.2

```
pip install pillow==8.3.2
```

check here https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6407